# VBA For each cycle with delete statement inside

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, each

I'm trying to do this for each statement but it starts a never ending loop on the first bookmark, don't know why.
The vba code simply changes the tag name of a word document already loaded with the names taken from sheet2 of the workbook "ToolImport.xlsm".

```
Public sub ChangeName(Document as Documento)
  Dim BK As Word.bookmark
  Dim rng As Word.Range
  Dim rwIndex As Integer
  Dim NomeBk As String

  Workbooks("ToolImport.xlsm").Activate
  Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate

  For Each BK In Documento.Bookmarks
    rwIndex = 1
    Do Until (IsNull(Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rwIndex, 4)))
      With Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rwIndex, 4)
        If .Value = Mid$(BK.Name, 1, 5) Then
          Set rng = BK.Range
          NomeBk = BK.Name
          BK.Delete
          rng.Bookmarks.Add (Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rwIndex, 2).Value & Mid$(NomeBk, 6, Len(NomeBk)))
          GoTo Prossimo:
        End If
      End With
      rwIndex = rwIndex + 1
    Loop

    Prossimo:
  Next BK
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Where's `documento.bookmarks` referring to?  The Word bookmarks? Or Excel bookmarks?  Are you trying to take a Word Document, and for each bookmar, place this into Excel? What's the overall goal?  Are you running this from Word, or in Excel?

Comment: Documento is a OBJDoc opened correctly previously in a function. The Word Document is already tagged and the for cycle just scans the word document and has to change all tag names from old names to new ones from the excel worksheets. I open the vba from an excel file.